# QQmlEngine symbols not found

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt5, qqmlcomponent

I'm getting a linker error that a whole host of symbols including `QQmlEngine` and `QQmlComponent` constructors are undefined, from the main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
#include <QtQml/QQmlComponent>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine eng;

    QQmlComponent component(&eng, QUrl::fromLocalFile("app.qml"));
    component.create();
}
```

I've run `qmake -project`, and rebuilt all.

Browsing other questions, and the docs, it seems the include should be `QQmlEngine`, but this is not found, and `QtQml/QQmlEngine` is. Are they one in the same, or is that the problem?

Comment: I'll edit the actual error output in in the morning, no WiFi at home at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your .pro file:

```
QT += qml quick
```

Comment: Ah that got it, thanks! Seems like 5 settings for every change sometimes! Now I'm getting 'component not ready' though, not sure if related?